# How to align 2 blocks vertically using leaders

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

I need to use fo:leader for create a table with requests and responses
like this:

[Table leader like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zYWY.jpg)

However the final result is like that:

[Both block align top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecoVy.jpg)

My problem is when the left block have 2 lines and the right block have 2 lines both of them align on top.
I need to align the left block on top and the right block on bottom.

Is that possible?

Follow the atual code:

```
<fo:inline-container vertical-align="top" inline-progression-dimension="60%">
<fo:block start-indent="0.5em" text-indent="-0.5em" text-align-last="justify" margin-right="0.3cm"<xsl:value-of select="challenge/para|limitdesc/para|sopitem/para"/>
<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/</fo:block>
</fo:inline-container>
<fo:inline-container relative-position="relative" vertical-align="bottom" display-align="after" inline-progression-dimension="40%">
<fo:block start-indent="0.5em" text-indent="-0.5em" display-align="after"><xsl:value-of select="response/para|limitvalue/para|limittext/para|act/para"/></fo:block>
</fo:inline-container>
```

Comment: Which formatter are you using?

Comment: AHFormatter 6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using AH Formatter and found two solutions.

[1] Use `baseline-shift` for the latter `fo:inline-container`

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:inline-container vertical-align="top" inline-progression-dimension="60%">
        <fo:block start-indent="0.5em" text-indent="-0.5em" text-align-last="justify">
            [1] Text here text here text here text here text here text here text here
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/></fo:block></fo:inline-container><fo:inline-container baseline-shift="-1.44em" inline-progression-dimension="40%">
        <fo:block start-indent="0.5em" text-indent="-0.5em" display-align="after">
            Continued text here text here text here text here
        </fo:block>
    </fo:inline-container>
</fo:block>
```

I specifies `baseline-shift="-1.44em". (This depends the used font) This method works only when the first line count equals 2.

[2] Use `fo:table` instead of `fo:inline-container`

```
<fo:table width="100%">
    <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="60%"/>
    <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="40%"/>
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block start-indent="0.5em" text-indent="-0.5em" text-align-last="justify">
                    [2] Text here text here text here text here text here text here text here
                    <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/></fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell/>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell/>
            <fo:table-cell padding-before="-1.32em">
                <fo:block start-indent="0.5em" text-indent="-0.5em" display-align="after">
                    Continued text here text here text here text here
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

This method does not depend the text lines in the first `fo:table-cell`.

The two formatting result using AH Formatter GUI:

[image: Formatting result in AH Formatter GUI]

My Formatter version is 6.4. But the result will be the same.

Comment: Thank you a lot! The second answer works perfectly.
Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer by @tmakita, you can use `alignment-baseline` to align the baselines of the two `fo:inline-container` (see discussion at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_inline-container).

You can use `last-line-end-indent` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#last-line-end-indent) to have the leader project past the end of the text, but you need to also constrain the width of the text.  In this example, I used an `fo:block-container` inside the first `fo:inline-container`:

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:inline-container vertical-align="top" inline-progression-dimension="60%" alignment-baseline="text-after-edge">
        <fo:block-container width="50%">
            <fo:block start-indent="0.5em" text-indent="-0.5em" text-align-last="justify" last-line-end-indent="-100%">
            [3] Text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here Text here text here text here text here text here text here text here<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" leader-length.minimum="50%" leader-length.optimum="50%"/></fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:inline-container><fo:inline-container inline-progression-dimension="40%">
                <fo:block start-indent="0.5em" text-indent="-0.5em">
                    Continued text here text here text here text here
                </fo:block>
            </fo:inline-container>
</fo:block>
```

Unless you want the text on the last line to be able to extend past the rest, the minimum and optimum leader length should be at least the width of the gap between the two sets of text.